# How to destructure an object and get values of one key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructure

Below is the json data that'd I'd like destructure and extract just the title values.

```
 [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Python Crash Course",
        "author": "Eric Matthes",
        "quantity": 5
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Head-First Python",
        "author": "Paul Barry",
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Is this an array of two objects? The json is not 100% valid, I guess the `[` is missing?

Comment: My bad. You're right. I've changed the json. And the body has 15 objects.

Comment: Which array index and which key? Try `[{title}]` for the first or `[,{author}]` for the second.  If you want all of them, you'll need to `map`.

Answer (score 1):

Getting specific properties of objects inside an array does not need destructuring. This can be done with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
jsonArray.map(object => object.title);
// results in ["Python Crash Course", "Head-First Python"]
```

If you really want to use destructuring, you could change the function provided to `map` to only select the title:

```
jsonArray.map(({title}) => title);
// results in ["Python Crash Course", "Head-First Python"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is an array of objects and it's in the file (not as an external file) then,

```
const arrayObj = [
   {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Head-First Python",
    "author": "Paul Barry",
    "quantity": 1
  },
  ...
]

const {title} = arrayObj[0]
console.log(title) //Head-First Python
```

That will give you the value of one object in the array.
To get all the 'title' properties you could loop through the array.

```
arrayObj.forEach(el => {
   let {title} = el
})
```